# Why does mypy reject my "mixed union" type declaration?

Tags: python, annotations, typing, mypy

While [troubleshooting a semi-related problem in the Python chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/49920836#49920836), I came upon some behavior in mypy that I don't understand.

```
from typing import Union, List, Dict

def f(x: Union[
            Dict[str, float],
            Dict[str, str],
            Dict[str, int],
    ]):
        pass

f({"a": 1})     #passes
f({"a": "b"})   #passes
f({"a": 1.0})   #passes

def g(x: Union[
            Dict[str, float],
            Dict[str, Union[str, int]],
    ]):
        pass

g({"a": 1})     #fails
g({"a": "b"})   #fails
g({"a": 1.0})   #passes

def h(x: Dict[str, Union[float, str, int]]):
    pass

h({"a": 1})     #passes
h({"a": "b"})   #passes
h({"a": 1.0})   #passes
```

When I execute mypy on this script, it only complains about the middle function, `g`:

```
C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop>mypy test.py
test.py:20: error: Argument 1 to "g" has incompatible type "Dict[str, int]"; expected "Union[Dict[str, float], Dict[str, Union[str, int]]]"
test.py:20: note: "Dict" is invariant -- see http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#variance
test.py:20: note: Consider using "Mapping" instead, which is covariant in the value type
test.py:21: error: Argument 1 to "g" has incompatible type "Dict[str, str]"; expected "Union[Dict[str, float], Dict[str, Union[str, int]]]"
test.py:21: note: "Dict" is invariant -- see http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#variance
test.py:21: note: Consider using "Mapping" instead, which is covariant in the value type
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

(As the notes imply, replacing `Dict` with `Mapping` removes the errors, but let's say for the sake of the question that I must use Dict.)

These errors are surprising to me. As far as I can tell, the type annotations for each function should simplify down to the same group of types: a dict whose keys are strings, and whose values are floats/strings/ints. So why does only `g` have incompatible types? Is mypy somehow confused by the presence of two Unions?

Comment: Similar case: A value (e.g. ``{'a': 1}``) satisfying ``Dict[str, Union[int, str]]`` also satisfies ``Union[str, Dict[str, Union[int, str]]]`` but not ``Union[Dict[int, str], Dict[str, Union[int, str]]]``.

Answer (score 7):

This is because `Dict` is invariant. It should be invariant because it is mutable.

`Dict[str, int]` is not a subtype of `Dict[str, Union[str, int]]` (even though `int` is a subtype of `Union[int, str]`)

What if you are going to do something like this:

```
d: Dict[str, Union[str, int]]
u: Dict[str, int]
d = u  # Mypy error: Incompatible type
d["Key"] = "value"
```

---

Mypy assumes that dictionaries are homogeneous: they will only ever contain one kind of type. In contrast to this, for example, `Tuples` are meant to contain heterogeneous data: each item is allowed to have a different type.

If you need heterogenous `Dict`, you could use [`TypedDict`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html#typeddict), but only a fixed set of string keys is expected:

```
from typing import List, TypedDict

Mytype = TypedDict('Mytype', {'x': str, 'a': List[str]})
s: Mytype = {"x": "y", "a": ["b"]}

s['a'].append('c')
```

NOTE:

> Unless you are on Python 3.8 or newer (where `TypedDict` is available in standard library typing module) you need to install typing_extensions using pip to use TypedDict

Comment: MyPy has no problem with ``d = {'a': 1}``. ``d["Key"].upper()`` being invalid is precisely because ``d``'s value has *explicitly* more than one possible concrete type – it behaves no different than ``e: Union[str, int]`` and ``e.upper()``.

Comment: Mypy doesn’t complain in case of literal initialization, but if one uses explicitly typed or implicitly inferred variable then it complains.

Comment: I would say this is a feature of type inference. It’s a sort of hard/soft constraints, when we do literal assignment (initialization) in simple case mypy uses soft constraint , but if it need to choose between Union variants or to do typed var assignment it uses hard.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that [`Union` membership is modelled as subtyping, yet `Dict` keys/values require exact type matches](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6001). This is enforced by MyPy for nested types (`g`), but loosely interpreted for direct substitution ( `h`).

---

The `Union` type is modelled as a (virtual) subtyping relation. That is, `str` is considered a subtype of `Union[str, x]`.

- This matches how `issubbclass(a, (str, int))` checks whether `a` is "either `str` or `int`" without saying which. We can use a `str` value in place of a `(str, int)`-union as long as only the common features are used.

The `Dict` type is invariant in its key/value types. That is, a key/value must be exactly of the type as declared.

- For a mutable type such as dict, the key/value are both *input* `d[k] = v` and *output* `v = d[k]`. Any substitute would have to work with *less capable* input or provide *more capable* output – which is not possible, since input and output must have the same capabilities.

In combination, using a `Dict[..., Union[str, ...]]` requires the value to match the `Union[str, ...]` exactly – the (virtual) subtype `str` is not valid. As such, `{"a": "b"}` is considered as `Dict[str, str]` which is not a substitute for `Dict[str, Union[str, int]]`.

---

Since *logically* a union follows slightly separate behaviour from regular types, MyPy has some [separate code paths for `Union`](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/db8de922a335d01a9681eacb81860190b611b4d8/mypy/subtypes.py#L118-L123). This is mostly focused on [function signatures and overloading](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5119), for which separate union math exists. Thus, certain flat type substitutions allows for more practical `Union` matching, as is the case for `h`.