# How to type annotate function which iterates over class instances or tuples of same class intances in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, mypy, type-annotation

I am starting experiment with type annotations in Python 3 and have a problem with a function `exclude_filter`, specifically annotating the `items` in following code snippet (I am posting this unannotated). Briefly speaking I am trying to iterate over a list and filter out some items based on some criteria. And the type of the item in list is either instance of class or tuple of those instances in which case I am looking for criteria only in first member of the tuple.

```
@dataclass
class BaseItem:
    name: str
    something: int

def exclude_filter(items, matches):
    def item_matched(item, matches):
        name = item[0].name if isinstance(item, tuple) else item.name
        for match in matches:
            if match in name:
                return True
        return False    
    items[:] = [i for i in items if not item_matched(i, matches)]

FOOS = [BaseItem("1st foo", 10), BaseItem("2nd foo", 11)]
BARS = [BaseItem("1st bar", 20), BaseItem("2nd bar", 22)]
FOOS_AND_BARS = list(zip(FOOS, BARS))

exclude_filter(FOOS, ["1st"])
exclude_filter(BARS, ["2nd"])
exclude_filter(FOOS_AND_BARS, ["1st"])

print(FOOS)
# [BaseItem(name='2nd foo', something=11)]
print(BARS)
# [BaseItem(name='1st bar', something=20)]
print(FOOS_AND_BARS)
# [(BaseItem(name='2nd foo', something=11), BaseItem(name='2nd bar', something=22))]
```

I've tried obviously wrong `items: List[BaseItem]` with result:

```
Argument 1 to "exclude_filter" has incompatible type "List[Tuple[BaseItem, BaseItem]]"; expected "List[BaseItem]"
```

So I've tried `item: List[Union[BaseItem, Tuple[BaseItem, BaseItem]]]`:

```
Argument 1 to "exclude_filter" has incompatible type "List[BaseItem]"; expected "List[Union[BaseItem, Tuple[BaseItem, BaseItem]]]"
```

Then I've tried `T = TypeVar("T", BaseItem, Tuple[BaseItem, BaseItem])` and `items: List[T]` a `item: T` but I got:

```
"Tuple[BaseItem, BaseItem]" has no attribute "name"
```

Well I tried even more obscure combinations but nothing seems to work. What is the correct way to annotate this code?

Comment: My bad, missed that one. This may be related to [Why does mypy reject my “mixed union” type declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62900750/why-does-mypy-reject-my-mixed-union-type-declaration)

Comment: Yes, this looks similar. But In my case I just can't replace `List` with `Sequence` to get rid of invariant problem (corresponds with `Dict` and `Mapping`) because I am using the `items[:]` syntax in function body. It just must be List.

Comment: So I find solution but not explanation. If I use `TypeVar` and change the one-line conditinal expression `name = item[0].name if isinstance(item, tuple) else item.name` to normal if-else block, then it works. Mypy probably can't handle conditional expressions with isinstance().

Comment: Note that the typevar as shown corresponds to ``Union[List[BaseItem], List[Tuple[BaseItem, ...]]]``, not ``List[Union[BaseItem, Tuple[BaseItem, BaseItem]]]``. The former does *not* match your description of the List possibly having *both* bare and tuple-nested ``BaseItem``s. Your examples do not test for this – is this use-case desirable?

Comment: In my case all lists are supposed to be homogenous, so `TypeVar` solution is actually OK. Interestingly `List[Tuple[BaseItem, ...]]` is not compatible with `List[Tuple[BaseItem, BaseItem]]` due to that invariant problem. It works with `Sequence` but not with `List`. Moreover `List[Tuple[BaseItem, ...]]` does represent a list with all same-length-tuples or every tuple can have different variable length? I will probably start discussion on mypy github.

Answer (score 0):

Well I've found working but ugly solution to this problem and sadly it only works for homogenous lists.

```
BaseItemOrTuple = TypeVar(
    "BaseItemOrTuple",
    BaseItem,
    Tuple[BaseItem, BaseItem],
    Tuple[BaseItem, BaseItem, BaseItem],
    Tuple[BaseItem, BaseItem, BaseItem, BaseItem],
    # Et cetera for longer tuples
)

def exclude_filter(items: List[BaseItemOrTuple], matches: Sequence[str]) -> None:
    def item_matched(item: BaseItemOrTuple, matches: Sequence[str]) -> bool:
        if isinstance(item, tuple): #  cannot use one-liner here due to possible mypy bug
            name = item[0].name 
        else:
            name = item.name
        for match in matches:
            if match in name:
                return True
        return False    
    items[:] = [i for i in items if not item_matched(i, matches)]
```

The biggest problem with `List` being invariant is this:

```
Argument 1 to "exclude_filter" has incompatible type "List[Tuple[BaseItem, BaseItem]]"; expected "List[Tuple[BaseItem, ...]]"
```

That is the reason I cannot use `Tuple[BaseItem, ....]` in `TypeVar` and I must explicitely state all possible tuple lengths. It will be OK if I am using `Sequence` but due to `items[:]` operation I can't.

Also there is probably bug in mypy with conditional expression and using `isinstance()` so I need to use proper if-else block.